# Edeliver failing to start release

Tags: deployment, elixir, edeliver

When running `mix edeliver version production` locally it fails with the following output

```
EDELIVER MYAPP WITH VERSION COMMAND

-----> getting release versions from production servers

production node:

  user    : app_user
  host    : my_app
  path    : /home/app_user/my_app.io
  response: bash: line 4: bin/my_app: No such file or directory

bash: line 47: bin/my_app: No such file or directory


VERSION DONE!
```

The error is obvious, as the executable lives in: `~/my_app.io/my_app/_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin`

I'm also unable to run any of the `start/stop/restart` etc commands

The deployment was successful because when I ssh in, and run the start command it works.

I would like to know if anyone can point me in the direction of some config parameter that I'm missing, as the local commands are a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem

I only built my app by running the following: `env MIX_ENV=prod mix edeliver build release`

I was probably too excited and forgot to actually deploy the release using something similar to the following `mix edeliver deploy release to production --version=0.0.1`

Hope someone else might benefit from this also.